# How to fix RX problem in Sender Based Orchestra Scheduling with CCA?

Tags: simulation, iot, contiki, cooja, orchestra

I am realizing a scenario of DAG root and DAG node in Contiki NG environment with Sender Based Orchestra while using UDP between nodes.But I have a problem of lack of RX in my Cooja Simulation after enabling Clear Channel Assesment(CCA) in my `project-conf.h` file. What should I change in my files to solve this problem?

I use one node for DAG root and one node for DAG node(while using the files under Contiki NG namely `udp-server.c` and `udp-client.c`). After CCA I have had an error like `!dl-miss TXbeforeTX 2800 2120` in the mote output of COOJA. As I get it there was a problem in timing. Therefore, I have changed the CCA offset(default is 1800 us) to 1000 us  and apparently it erased the warning. But this approach did not work on lack of RX in especially sender based unicast and EB slotframes. While seeing TX for mentioned slotframes, RX could not be observed. I could see in the mote output that the node tries to send a packet but it is never acknowledged. Also after sometime I have observed that the nodes were leaving the network.

I expect to have a RX slots for EB and Sender based unicast slotframes as well but actual result is I am getting RX just for Broadcast slotframe.
What should I change in my configuration files?

Comment: CCA is not super well tested feature in TSCH - it is possible there are bugs in the implementation. Try Contiki-NG gitter: https://gitter.im/contiki-ng/Developers